# Derivative of integral of $\sin (t^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, derivatives, definite-integrals

I'm stuck with the problem

> If $ F(x)=\int_0^{x^3} \sin t^2 dt$  find $F'(x)$

Now, if the upper interval were $x$, the answer would be $\sin t^2$ (right?). However, the upper interval is $x^3$.

I've thought of just working through the integral and then taking the derivative of the answer, but I don't have a clue how to integrate $\sin t^2$ (not $\sin^2t$). I'm not sure if this is even integrable. If it isn't, is the problem solvable at all?

We can't just put $x^3$ in for $t$, so I'm out of ideas of how to solve this problem.

Comment: Chain rule. If $G(x)=\int_0^x \sin t^2\,dt$, then $F(x)=G(x^3)$

Comment: I don't think I've ever used the chain rule with integration. So, we don't have to bother integrating $sin t^2$ then?

Comment: Right, you don't have to integrate. You have a function $G(x)=\int_0^x \sin t^2\,dt$.  Its derivative is $G'(x)=\sin x^2$.  By the chain rule $$[F(x)]'=[G(x^3)]'=G'(x^3)\cdot(x^3)' =(\sin (x^3)^2)\cdot3x^2.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general,
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{u(x)}^{v(x)}f(t)dt=f(v(x))v^\prime(x)-f(u(x))u^\prime(x).$$
So, in your case, letting $f(t)=\sin(t^2),$
$$\begin{align}F^\prime(x)&=f(x^3)(x^3)^\prime-f(0)\cdot 0\\&=\sin\{(x^3)^2\}\cdot 3x^2-0\\&=3x^2\sin(x^6).\end{align}$$

Comment: so in his case it would be $sin(x^3)*3*x^2$ ?

Comment: NO. $F^\prime(x)=\sin\{(x^3)^2\}\cdot 3x^2.$

Comment: aaa,i forgot power

Answer (score 3):

Let $G(t)$ be an *antiderivative* of $\sin(t^2)$

Then $$\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^{x^3} \sin(t^2) dt = \frac{d}{dx} G(x^3)-G(0) = 3x^2G'(x^3) = 3x^2\sin(x^6)$$

Comment: I made an edit. The line of approach is the same.