# A derivative of an integral question

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Hi I have some question about a derivative of an integral.

$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{x}e^{-u^{2}}du\right)
 $

My try to solve

$\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{x}e^{-u^{2}}du=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{0}^{x}e^{-u^{2}}du\right)-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x}}e^{-u^{2}}du\right)
 $

What should I do from here ?

Should I solve the integral for $du$ straight away and then differentiate ? How should I approach ?

I feel that I am stuck...

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: You will not succeed in integrating $e^{-u^2}$ (neither would I). Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: @André Nicolas I was told to use the fundamental theorem of calculus but!!! - I have no idea how to apply it here ! could you please give me the way how to solve this kind of problems I'm preparing for a quiz tomorrow and I need to know this :(

Comment: There is now a brief answer. [Here is](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638217/derivative-of-integral-of-sin-t2?rq=1) another question that involves the same idea. You can undoubtedly find others on MSE by searching, search term Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of calculus says that for continuous functions $f$, we have $$\frac d{dx}\int^x_0 f(u)du =f(x).$$ And hence by the chain rule, for and differentiable $g$, $$\frac d{dx}\int^{g(x)}_0 f(u)du =f(g(x))g'(x).$$

Comment: Then this means that :

By setting the indefinite integral $\int e^{-u^{2}}du=F(u)
 $

$\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{x}e^{-u^{2}}du=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{0}^{x}e^{-u^{2}}du\right)-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x}}e^{-u^{2}}du\right)=
 $

$\frac{d}{dx}\left(F(x)\right)-\frac{d}{dx}\left(F(\sqrt{x})\right)=e^{-x^{2}}-\left(\left(\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)e^{-\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^{2}}\right)=
 $

$=e^{-x^{2}}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}e^{-x}
 $

Please let me know if I am correct on this one ?

Answer (score 0):

It equals $$e^{-x^2}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}e^{-x}$$

By simple leibnitz rule of differentiation of an integral .
Which is same as above.