# Partial derivatives of a multi variable integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Find $\dfrac{∂f}{∂x}$ and $\dfrac{∂f}{∂y}$ for$$f(x, y)=\int_{x+y}^{x-y}\sin t^3\,\mathrm dt.$$

I looked around before posting this and got a solution but I am not sure if it is right. I got that $\dfrac{∂f}{∂x}$ and $\dfrac{∂f}{∂y}$ were both $3\sin(x-y)(x-y)^2 - 3\sin(x+y)(x+y)^2$ using [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638217/derivative-of-integral-of-sin-t2?newreg=d513fec0d27b437caeab736baefb6cef) as a guide.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not correct. When we apply the chain rule here, the only things we're differentiating are the limits of the integral. The derivative never goes far enough inside to hit that $t^3$. In fact, to remove the temptation there? Let's just call the function we're integrating $g(t)$, and plug in the formula for it at the last possible moment.
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_{x+y}^{x-y}g(t)\,dt = g(x-y)\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x-y) - g(x+y)\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x+y) = g(x-y)-g(x+y)$$
And then, $g(x-y)-g(x+y)=\sin\left((x-y)^3\right)-\sin\left((x+y)^3\right)$. That's the partial derivative in $x$. I leave the other as an exercise, to show that you understand this.

Comment: Thank you!  I think I understand it correctly now.  The derivative in y would be the same in this case because both the limits of integration only have a variable to the first degree, but if the upper limit had been something like x - y^2, then the partial derivatives would be different

Comment: Well, mostly the same. Some of the signs are different. And yes, if we had something like $x-y^2$ in the limit, the derivative $-2y$ would show up there.

Comment: Oh thank you! I just caught where they are different.  Whoops lol.  Thanks again!